# select event on grid is called when i try and sort

Tags: extjs, extjs-mvc, extjs4.1

I have the following in my controller. This is use to edit the selected row. This does as is intended however this event is also called when i click on the field name to sort the column.

```
'#cutterGrid':{
                select :this.onCutterSelect
            },
```

Am i using the best event here. I'm using extjs 4.1

Comment: Could you host somewhere the application that reproduces it? (then I could debug it, otherwise too boring to set it up locally) PS: if you do that - please use `ext-debug.js`

Comment: It seems you have some other cause. I tested locally it's working correctly. just in case check selected record to avoid.